# Using drawInRect on a view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I have a drawInRect method which I wish to use on another UIView, a subview of this view.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you mean you have a view that draws something and you'd like that same something to be drawn smaller, somewhere within the view?  Like an infinite regress?  This is doable, but you'll need to take steps to insure that it's not actually infinite.  Happy to answer if that's the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in duplicating the drawing, you could put your drawing in a separate function (`drawFunct`) of the top level view, and just call `[self.superview drawFunct]` from within the subviews  `drawInRect`.

Calling the  `drawInRect` is generally discouraged.